# Запрос SQL с выборкой уникальных значений по дате и времени создания

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица

```
users_com
------------
id |  user_id  |  create_datetime
1     102765    2020-01-28 9:05:11
2     102765    2020-01-28 10:05:22
3     102765    2020-01-28 11:05:55
4     104566    2020-01-28 9:05:44
5     104566    2020-01-28 12:05:52
6     104566    2020-01-28 14:05:34
```

Нужен запрос результатом которого станет:

```
   users_com.id  | users_com.user_id
        3               102765 
        6               104566
```

На сервере с MySQL 5.6 конструкция ниже отрабатывает правильно, на другом MySQL 5.7.26 не работает. Я так понимаю какой-то отвечает параметр за это? Можете подсказать куда копать? Спасибо.

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT `id` as i, `user_id` as u, `create_datetime` as d FROM `users_com`
                ORDER BY d DESC
            ) AS one
            WHERE u IN (102765, 104566)
GROUP BY u
```

Comment: *На сервере с MySQL 5.6 конструкция ниже отрабатывает правильно* Это - всего лишь случайность. В любой момент она может перестать давать верный результат.

Comment: Как понять случайность. Запрос, который я привел, отрабатывает успешно на одном сервере, а на другом не хочет с такой же структурой данных.

Comment: Вот об этом и речь. Когда выполняется группировка по одному полю, а другие поля не "обернуты" групповой функций, для них возвращается ЛЮБОЕ возможное значение из всех значений в группе. У тебя для одного юзера 3 разных id - возвращается любой из них. На одном сервере по неким внутренним причинам это любое оказалось тем, какое нужно, на другом - не тем. И управлять этим - нельзя даже теоретически. Более того, в любой момент возвращаемое значение для тех же запроса и данных  может измениться, на то оно и любое из.

Comment: Не знал о таких особенностях.

Comment: [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) - изучайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(id) id, user_id
FROM users_com
-- WHERE user_id IN (102765, 104566)
GROUP BY users_com
```

Если порядок `id` может не соответствовать порядку `create_datetime`, то

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id 
                             ORDER BY create_datetime DESC) id,
       user_id
FROM users_com
-- WHERE user_id IN (102765, 104566)
```

То же для версии 5+

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.user_id
FROM users_com t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT t2.user_id, MAX(t2.create_datetime) create_datetime 
               FROM users_com t2
               -- WHERE user_id IN (102765, 104566
               GROUP BY t2.user_id ) t3
-- WHERE user_id IN (102765, 104566)
```

PS. Надеюсь, для одного и того же `user_id` значения `create_datetime` не дублируются?

> `create_datetime` могут дублироваться

Тогда для заявленной версии сервера 5.7.26

```
SELECT MAX(t1.id) id, t1.user_id
FROM users_com t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT t2.user_id, MAX(t2.create_datetime) create_datetime 
               FROM users_com t2
               -- WHERE user_id IN (102765, 104566
               GROUP BY t2.user_id ) t3
-- WHERE user_id IN (102765, 104566)
GROUP BY t1.user_id
```

Comment: `create_datetime` могут дублироваться

Comment: Благодарю! Забыл указать, что да, сортировка по последней дате изменения. Возможно можно оптимизировать запрос. Хотя итак рабочий

Comment: Но лучше сортировка по ID конечно же.